# Using Python and imgkit, the output is not as expected based on html rendered in browser

Tags: python, html, css, wkhtmltoimage, imgkit

I am using imgkit and html/css to make tables containing data from a dataframe. The html/css I have looks as it should when rendered in a browser, but the image rendered by imgkit has horizontal gaps in row 3 and in the green background.

imgkit output:[image]:

What it should be like:

[image]

The HTML/CSS code

```
<head>
    <style>
        #box {
          width: 750px;
          height: 250px;
          display: table;
        }
        table {
          font-family: Arial;
          color: #000000;
          font-size: 8pt;
          padding: 0px;
          margin: 0px;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          min-height: 70%;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          border-spacing: 0;
        }
        td, tr {
        padding: 0px;
        }
        .border-right {
          border-right: 2px solid #29577e;
        }
        .border-bottom, .border-bottom td {
          border-bottom: 2px solid #29577e;
        }
        .dash {
          border-bottom: 1px dashed #29577e;
        }
        .bold {
          font-weight: bold;
        }
        .right {
          text-align: right;
        }
        .col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-7 {
          text-align: left;
        }
        .col-1 {
        }
        .indent1 {
          text-indent: 20px;
        }
        .indent2 {
          text-indent: 40px;
        }
        .green {
          background-color: #d5eff0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

    <div id="box">
      <table cellpadding="0">
        <tr class="index top bold">
          <th class="col-1"><th>
          <th class="col-2"><th>
          <th class="col-3"><th>
          <th class="col-4 right">L12M<th>
          <th class="col-5 right">L3M<th>
          <th class="col-6 border-right right">L1M<th>
          <th class="col-7"><th>
          <th class="col-8 right">L12M<th>
          <th class="col-9 right">L3M<th>
          <th class="col-10 border-right right">L1M<th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="index bottom bold">
          <th class="col-1">Revenue (K�)<th>
          <th class="col-2"><th>
          <th class="col-3"><th>
          <th class="col-4 right"><th>
          <th class="col-5 right"><th>
          <th class="col-6 border-right right"><th>
          <th class="col-7">BV waterfall (K�)<th>
          <th class="col-8 right"><th>
          <th class="col-9 right"><th>
          <th class=" col-10 border-right right"><th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-1">
          <td class="col-1"><td>
          <td class="col-2">Total Collections<td>
          <td class="col-2"><td>
          <td class="col-4 right">147,499<td>
          <td class="col-5 right">40,734<td>
          <td class="col-6 border-right right">12,116<td>
          <td class="col-7 bold indent1 dash">BV (BoP)<td>
          <td class="col-8 bold dash right">200,501<td>
          <td class="col-9 bold dash right">189,658<td>
          <td class="col-10 border-right bold dash right">148,963<td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-2">
          <td class="col-1"><td>
          <td class="col-2 dash">Amortization<td>
          <td class="col-3 dash"><td>
          <td class="col-4 dash right">6,499<td>
          <td class="col-5 dash right">-1,734<td>
          <td class="col-6 border-right dash right">-2,116<td>
          <td class="col-7 indent1">New Purchase<td>
          <td class="col-8 right">22,342<td>
          <td class="col-9 right">3,264<td>
          <td class="col-10 border-right right">877<td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-3">
          <td class="col-1 border-bottom"><td>
          <td class="col-2 border-bottom bold">Revenue<td>
          <td class="col-3 border-bottom"><td>
          <td class="col-4 border-bottom right">154,499<td>
          <td class="col-5 border-bottom right">39,734<td>
          <td class="col-6 border-bottom border-right right">9,116<td>
          <td class="col-7 green indent2 ">Regular<td>
          <td class="col-8 green right">13,704<td>
          <td class="col-9 green right">1,701<td>
          <td class="col-10 border-right green right">602<td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-4">
          <td class="col-1 bold">Costs (K�)<td>
          <td class="col-2"><td>
          <td class="col-3"><td>
          <td class="col-4 right"><td>
          <td class="col-5 right"><td>
          <td class="col-6 border-right right"><td>
          <td class="col-7 green indent2">PRE4<sup>3</sup><td>
          <td class="col-8 green right">8,638<td>
          <td class="col-9 green right">1,563<td>
          <td class="col-10 border-right green right">274<td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-5">
          <td class="col-1"><td>
          <td class="col-2 bold">Comm<td>
          <td class="col-3">FC (c-a)<td>
          <td class="col-4 right">32,371<td>
          <td class="col-5 right">9,254<td>
          <td class="col-6 border-right right">2,875<td>
          <td class="col-7 indent1">Purc. Price Changes<td>
          <td class="col-8 right">-8,274<td>
          <td class="col-9 right">-2,393<td>
          <td class="col-10 border-right right">-784<td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-6">
          <td class="col-1"><td>
          <td class="col-2 dash"><td>
          <td class="col-3 dash">Actuals<td>
          <td class="col-4 dash right">37,371<td>
          <td class="col-5 dash right">11,254<td>
          <td class="col-6 border-right dash right">3,875<td>
          <td class="col-7 indent1">Amortization<td>
          <td class="col-8 right">6,950<td>
          <td class="col-9 right">-1,427<td>
          <td class="col-10 border-right right">-2,495
          <td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-7">
          <td class="col-1"><td>
          <td class="col-2 bold">Unremitted<td>
          <td class="col-3">FC (c-a)<td>
          <td class="col-4 right">7,980<td>
          <td class="col-5 right">2,300<td>
          <td class="col-6 border-right right">541<td>
          <td class="col-7 indent2 green">Normal Amortization<td>
          <td class="col-8 green right">-32,017<td>
          <td class="col-9 green right">-9,167<td>
          <td class="col-10 border-right green right">-2,495<td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-8">
          <td class="col-1"><td>
          <td class="col-2 dash"><td>
          <td class="col-3 dash">Actuals<td>
          <td class="col-4 dash right">16,700<td>
          <td class="col-5 dash right">3,741<td>
          <td class="col-6 border-right dash right">756<td>
          <td class="col-7 indent2 green">Revaluation<td>
          <td class="col-8 green right">38,967<td>
          <td class="col-9 green right">7,740<td>
          <td class="col-10 border-right green right">0<td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-9">
          <td class="col-1"><td>
          <td class="col-2 bold">Total<sup>2</sup><td>
          <td class="col-3">FC (c-a)<td>
          <td class="col-4 right">98,2%<td>
          <td class="col-5 right">30,1%<td>
          <td class="col-6 border-right right">54,4%<td>
          <td class="col-7 dash indent1">Currency Diff. Effect<td>
          <td class="col-8 dash right">2,787<td>
          <td class="col-9 dash right">-541<td>
          <td class="col-10 dash border-right right">4,653<td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row-10  border-bottom">
          <td class="col-1"><td>
          <td class="col-2"><td>
          <td class="col-3">Actuals<td>
          <td class="col-4 right">16.7%<td>
          <td class="col-5 right">41.8%<td>
          <td class="col-6 border-right right">75.6%<td>
          <td class="col-7 bold indent1">BV (EoP)<td>
          <td class="col-8 bold right">194,477<td>
          <td class="col-9 bold right">194,477<td>
          <td class="col-10 bold border-right right">194,477<td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

https://codepen.io/maryj25/pen/KKqVKmJ

Any advice how to fix that is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, collapsing the borders of table cells, or adjusting the border spacings in your css may help (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp). Can you check that?

Comment: @ihpar that's what I did to make it work on CodePen and in browser, but somehow it's not working when rendered in imgkit

Comment: sorry, I should've missed that... Your css looks to be correct for your purposes. Other than submitting a bug to https://github.com/jarrekk/imgkit/issues I have no idea, wish you the best of luck.

Comment: @ihpar thank you for trying! I'll submit a bug, thanks for the link.